# Always out of memory after some loop when try to loop Neural Network model training for many types of classification with tensorflow GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, out-of-memory

I am new to TensorFlow, I am training 1 type of Neural Network model for different types of classification, with same database so I am using for loop to train different classification with flow like:

make model -> get dataset -> model.fit -> save weight -> make model -> get dataset -> model.fit ->
.....  (repeat until all classification are trained)

when I train up to 2 types of classification and start to train the 3rd I always got error said cannot allocate memory

I have been using

```
a_path = f"wav_data/denoise/{index[i]}"
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=training(a_path, load=False))
p.start()
p.join()
p.kill()
p.close()
```

with training() as training function and still get the error

and tried using

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus:
   tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)

tf.keras.backend.clear_session
gc.collect()
```

but still not working
TF 2.5

Comment: You shouldn't really do this. Each of the processes will try to grab the necessary amount of VRAM but if you spawn too many processes you'll always be running out of memory. Maybe check this out https://sefiks.com/2019/03/20/tips-and-tricks-for-gpu-and-multiprocessing-in-tensorflow/

Comment: when I used multiprocessing to train my model every classification then kill it why GPU memory still allocated and not freed?

Comment: Its multiprocessing, you are running multiple training sessions in parallel...

Comment: then if I use multiprocessing to train only 1 training session, with join() and then kill it then initiate another multiprocessing to train the next session of training, why memory for the last session still affect new session that can cause "cannot allocate memory" error?

Comment: Why use multiprocessing then?

Comment: the what to do? so I can train my classification model without causing "memory full" error as GPU will be full after 2nd model training if I use for, as I found in internet spawning this process in multiprocessing() can free the memory after model has been used, but not work for me

Comment: I don't understand why you need multiprocessing here. Just train them in a loop.

Comment: and that is precisely the problem. Whenever I use the loop at the 2nd iteration TensorFlow will give me error that cannot allocate memory for the next iteration training, so I am asking solution so I can train different classifications, let say 10 classifications, and I found on the internet to use multiprocessing(),gc.collect, clear_sessio() to free my training model that already trained, not working, as it will stay at GPU memory even after the training for that model was done, that make me cant train another 8 models.

Comment: Why not use Google Colaboratory? It has free Graphics Processing Unit and a lot of memeory.

Comment: that was a good proposition, but what I want to know is how to solved that problem with exhausted memory, because it'll and still be a problem even with good Graphics Processing and a lot of memory as there are big data Machine Learning out there, and that solution isn't solving the question, just make the problem less likely to appear but still "can happen", and by doing that, when it finally happens there won't have a solution for that.
(and sorry for the late reply)